# Fill up column with random values from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables. Table `Table_View` has 5 columns and 200 rows
and `Table_Random` has 3 columns with 10 rows
I need to poulate column `Table_View.A_random` with values from 
`Table_Random.FixValues`. If the query reaches the end of row in `Table_Random` `i.e row 10`, it should start again with
values from the top row `i.e row 1`. until it fills up the `200` rows. 
Given that all tables has `primary keys`.

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that if you provide tables structures, sample data and explain expected result more clearly you'll get the answer faster.

Comment: How random? I usually take two different modulo's and get "semi-random" data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for any count of rows in destination and source tables.
The idea is to calculate count of rows in random table and then assign number `rn % @c` to each row in destination table. And then update based on join:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 21
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @c INT = 0

DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, Random INT )
DECLARE @r TABLE ( ID INT, Random INT )

INSERT  INTO @r
VALUES  ( 1, 10 ),
        ( 3, 20 ),
        ( 4, 30 ),
        ( 6, 40 ),
        ( 8, 50 ),
        ( 11, 60 ),
        ( 14, 70 ),
        ( 17, 80 ),
        ( 19, 90 ),
        ( 21, 100 )

WHILE @i <= @count
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @t
        VALUES  ( @i, NULL )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END;

SELECT  @c = COUNT(*)
FROM    @r;


WITH    ctet1
          AS ( SELECT   * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             ),
        ctet2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CASE WHEN rn % @c = 0 THEN @c
                             ELSE rn % @c
                        END AS rnn
               FROM     ctet1
             ),
        cter
          AS ( SELECT   * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) AS rn
               FROM     @r
             )

    UPDATE  ct
    SET     Random = cr.Random
    FROM    ctet2 ct
            JOIN cter cr ON cr.rn = ct.rnn

SELECT  * FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
ID  Random
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
7   70
8   80
9   90
10  100
11  10
12  20
13  30
14  40
15  50
16  60
17  70
18  80
19  90
20  100
21  10
```

If you didn't want cycle update then no need for views, functions and needless stuff. Just update:

```
UPDATE @t SET Random = (SELECT TOP 1 Random FROM @r ORDER BY NEWID())
```

Answer (score 1):

> yes you can make this out.

First of all you need to create and view which'll return a single value from Random Table(`Table_Random`) for every call.

```
Create View vMyRand as 
Select top 1 val from myRand order by NewID();
```

then create a function to return value from created view.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMyRand ()
RETURNS varchar(5)
--WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
Declare @RetValue varchar(5)
--@configVar =
Select @RetValue = val from vmyRand
RETURN(@retValue)
END;
```

[Fiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41cf0/1)

**Full Code:**

```
create table tab_1
(
  id bigint identity(1,1),
  name varchar(50),
  email varchar(50)
  )

  insert into tab_1(name,email) values
  ('a','a@mail.com'),  ('b','c@mail.com'),
    ('a1','a1@mail.com'),  ('a2','a2@mail.com'),
      ('a3','a3@mail.com'),  ('a4','a4@mail.com'),
      ('b1','b1@mail.com'),('b2','b2@mail.com')

   create table myRand(val varchar(50))

   insert into myRand values('Q1654'),('F2597'),
   ('Y9405'),('B6735'),('D8732'),('C4893'),('I9732'),
   ('L1060'),('H6720');

Create View vMyRand as 
Select top 1 val from myRand order by NewID();

CREATE FUNCTION GetMyRand ()
RETURNS varchar(5)
--WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
Declare @RetValue varchar(5)
--@configVar =
Select @RetValue = val from vmyRand
RETURN(@retValue)
END;
```

**Update Code:**

```
update tab_1 set name=(select dbo.getMyRand())
```

Hope This'll Help You.
Thanks. :)

Comment: Hmmm, very strange. `If the query reaches the end of row in Table_Random i.e row 10, it should start again with values from the top row i.e row 1`, from here it sounds like you want to take random values in cycle.